# Wrapping columns in an Acumatica tabular report

Tags: acumatica

We have a report requirement of printing Inventory Items from SOLine table in tabular format. We have achieved this using tabular format, but now the issue is we need only 3 columns at a time. How can we do this?

[image]

Right now we are getting result like this.

[image]

Comment: Would it help readers if you were to show what you have already, and the code/config that you used to set it up?

Comment: Hi @halfer, i have updated question with what result we are getting now.

Comment: InventoryID is name of the column in database?